# javascript to group array of objects by key

Tags: javascript

I am trying to group an array of objects like the below using JavaScript.

```
const array = [
  { 'red':  50 , 'green':99 , 'blue': 66},
  {'blue':65, 'red': 88 }, 
  { 'green':9 , 'blue': 6},
  { 'red':  650 , 'green':959 , 'blue': 663},
];
```

and expecting the below result,

```
{
    red: [50, 88, 650],
    green: [99,9,959],
    blue: [66,65, 6, 663]
}
```

Can we implement this using **Reduce function?**

Thanks in advance!.

Comment: Can you please share your attempt to solve this?

Comment: Excuse me if this isn't the case, but your question reads as though you're a student looking for help with an assignment. There's no rule against this, but there are [suggestions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/11751077) that might help you get the sort of response you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below approach to do so. Hope it helps

Loop through the `array` and it's items. If the key already exists inside the `outputObj` object push the new value into the respective array, else simply create a new array with that key and value (`outputObj[key] = [item[key]]`).

**Working code:**

```js
const array = [{
    'red': 50,
    'green': 99,
    'blue': 66
  },
  {
    'blue': 65,
    'red': 88
  },
  {
    'green': 9,
    'blue': 6
  },
  {
    'red': 650,
    'green': 959,
    'blue': 663
  },
];

//Method 1
const outputObj = {};

array.forEach(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if (key in outputObj) {
      outputObj[key].push(item[key])
    } else {
      outputObj[key] = [item[key]]
    }
  })
})

console.log(outputObj)

//Method 2
const finalObj = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const obj = Object.keys(acc).length ? acc : {}
  Object.keys(curr).forEach(key => {
    if (key in obj) {
      obj[key].push(curr[key])
    } else {
      obj[key] = [curr[key]]
    }
  })
  return obj;
}, {})

console.log(finalObj)
```

Comment: It helps. Thanks for your effort!. Can we try using reduce function?

Comment: sure @Nithya. I've updated my answer. pls check (added method 2 - using reduce funcion to do the same thing)

Comment: Thankyou so much for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

```js
  array = [
    { red: 50, green: 99, blue: 66 },
    { blue: 65, red: 88 },
    { green: 9, blue: 6 },
    { red: 650, green: 959, blue: 663 },
  ];
  
  let result = {};
    for (let item of this.array) {
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(item)) {
        if (!result.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          result[key] = [value];
        } else {
          result[key].push(value);
        }
      }
    }
    
    console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code will fill the result object grouping values coming from the same key in the array variable:

```
var result = {};

array.forEach(
  item => Object.keys(item).forEach(
        key => {
            if (result[key] === undefined) result[key] = [];
            result[key].push(item[key]);
        }
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array = [
  { 'red':  50 , 'green':99 , 'blue': 66},
  {'blue':65, 'red': 88 }, 
  { 'green':9 , 'blue': 6},
  { 'red':  650 , 'green':959 , 'blue': 663},
];

function group(array, result = {}) {
  array.forEach(object => {
    Object.keys(object).forEach(key => {
      if(!result[key]) {
        result[key] = [object[key]];
        return;
      }

      result[key].push(object[key]);
    });
  });

  return result;
}

const result = group(array);

console.log(result);
```